# Can an ANSI C-compliant implementation include additional functions in its standard library?

Tags: c, standards, osx-lion, getline, ansi-c

Is an ANSI C-compliant implementation allowed to include additional types and functions in its standard library, beyond those enumerated by the standard?  (An ideal answer would reference the relevant part of the ANSI standard.)

I ask particularly because Mac OS 10.7 declares the `getline` function in stdio.h, even when compiling with gcc or clang using the `-ansi` flag.  This breaks several older programs that define their own `getline` function.  Is this a fault of Mac OS 10.7?  (The man page for `getline` on Mac OS 10.7 says that `getline` conforms to the POSIX.1 standard, which came in 2008.)

Edit:  To clarify, I find it odd that including stdio.h in an ANSI C89 program on Mac OS 10.7 also pulls in the declaration for the `getline` function, since `getline` is not one of the functions enumerated in the K&R (and presumably ANSI) description of stdio.h.  In particular, attempting to compile [noweb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/):

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic    -c -o notangle.o notangle.c
In file included from notangle.nw:28:
getline.h:4: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
/usr/include/stdio.h:449: error: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
```

Is it a bug in Mac OS 10.7 includes the declaration of `getline` in stdio.h even when compiling for the ANSI C89 standard?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From section 7.1.3 paragraph 2 of n1570 (which is a draft of C1x):

> No other identifiers are reserved.

This is the part that means `getline` shouldn't be defined by the `<stdio.h>`, since it's not a reserved identifier according to the spec.  So if your library defines `getline` in `<stdio.h>`, it's not technically compliant with the C standard...

However, you *should* be able to use the feature test macros to cause `getline` to be undefined in `<stdio.h>`.

```
#undef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <stdio.h>
```

This will give you only the definitions from the older POSIX standards.  This won't work on some GNU C++ implementations, which is **ExTrEmeLY fruSTRaTiNG** for some folks.

The relevant section of the manpage is (taken from a glibc manpage, sorry...)

```
   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       getline(), getdelim():
           Since glibc 2.10:
               _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700
           Before glibc 2.10:
               _GNU_SOURCE
```

This part of the manpage tells you which macros need to be defined to which values in order to get the definition.  My bet is that `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is already defined by your compiler to `200809L`.

The idea of feature test macros is that if you define your macros, like `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, etc. to the values you want, you won't need to worry about new library functions clashing with your existing functions.  There is also `_GNU_SOURCE`, which turns *everything* on if you use glibc, but I suggest giving that macro a wide berth.

Comment: Your answer has allowed me to get the ANSI C89 code compiling again, via defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 1`.  (This value is supposed to enable only the ANSI C89/ISO C90 features.)  These feature test macros are not documented in the Mac man page for `getline`, and the `feature_test_macros` man page doesn't exist on the Mac.  I wouldn't have found them without your answer.  Although your answer now doesn't answer my original question (is an ANSI C implementation *allowed* to declare other functions in its standard library), your answer addresses my actual problem.  I would upvote twice if I could!

Comment: The part of the standard that says "No other identifiers are reserved" means that the implementation is not technically allowed to define other functions in its headers, but I wasn't exactly clear about that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a compliant implementation is allowed to define additional identifiers, including functions, as long as they are one of the reserved identifiers in the standard.  For example:

- All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
  underscore are always reserved for any use;
- All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
  with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces;
- All external names that begin with `is`, `to`, `str`, `mem` or `wcs` followed by a lowercase letter;

In addition there are names that are reserved only if you include certain headers; for example, if you include `<errno.h>` then it can define any macro starting with `E` followed by a digit or uppercase letter.

However, `getline()` is *not* such a reserved name, and a compliant implementation must make it available for the programmer's own use.

Comment: This is _almost_ the answer I am looking for.  Do you have a reference that justifies your claim that `getline()` must be available for the programmer's own use?

Comment: @Bradford Larsen: The C standard ([N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is the final C99 standard as updated by TC1, TC2 and TC3).  In particular see sections 7.1.3 and 7.26.