# error: "an array may not have elements of this type"

Tags: c, arrays

What I want to do is declare a multidimensional array in C (not C++), where I will store a text in english and greek language as well. But compiler always gives error. My code is below:

```
#define _TLANG 2 //TOTAL LANGUAGES
char blankStr[_TLANG ][] = {{"HI!"}, {"HELLO"}};
```

but I get an error: `Error[Pe098]: an array may not have elements of this type`.

How can I overcome this?

The idea is to store all my texts in this array, something like:

```
char blankStr[_TLANG ][] = {
                        {{"HI!"},     {"HELLO"}}, //text1 (english and then greek
                        {{"GOOD MORNING"}, {"GOOD NIGHT"}}   //text2 etc
                      };
```

Comment: `_TL` is a reserved identifier

Comment: @MByD - I believe ANSI C reserves any identifier which begins with an `_` followed by a capital letter.

Comment: @awoodland: This is impossible. All my defines are starting with _ followed by capital letters.

Comment: @alexx - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376566/can-an-ansi-c-compliant-implementation-include-additional-functions-in-its-stand/7377431#7377431 they're reserved - that doesn't mean they have to be used, but it does mean you shouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

It should be either:

```
char blankStr[][_TL] = {" ", " "};
```

or

```
const char * blankStr[][_TL] = {{" "}, {" "}};
```

As string is a char array.

Comment: Hello MByD. Unfortunately the same mistake is also produced with both of your suggestions.

Comment: @alexxx: you mean you still get a compiler error? This does not mean it is because of a (the same) mistake :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is from this mistake. This project is compiled and functional inside a microcontroller. I only added this part and get this error. When this lingoes away, the error dissapears also.

Comment: @MByD: I am terribly sorry for the lack of my explanations, please see my edited original post on the top, just to see what I want to achieve. You will understand that I cannot use a solution like that. But I'm telling you again that this is my fault and not yours, because I didn't explain well in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are write `"abc"` in initialization, it is like writing `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` which is an array itself. So when you write:

```
char blankStr[_TL][] = {{" "}, {" "}};
```

You are actually saying:

```
char blankStr[_TL][] = {{{' ', '\0'}}, {{' ', '\0'}}};
```

Which is a 2d array being initialized by a 3d array. Simply dropping the extra `{}`s will get you what you need:

```
char blankStr[_TL][] = {" ", " "};
```

Note by the way that `_TL` is a reserved word (staring `_` followed by an upper-case letter).

The way I do it, is to prefix the constant name with the library name, or sometimes my own initials. For example, if I want to define window size, I'd say:

```
#define SH_WIDTH 1980
#define SH_HEIGHT 1080
```

as opposed to `_W` and `_H` for example!

Comment: I like how you made the null chars explicit

Comment: I changed _TL into _TLANG but nothing changed, so I believe the problem could not be that.

Comment: @sehe, I love `'\0'`! Kinda my coding style.