# previous declaration of 'function' was here in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning C by K&R, error when trying to compile programs from book with arrays and function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763052/learning-c-by-kr-error-when-trying-to-compile-programs-from-book-with-arrays-a)

While learning The C Programming Language by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie, I tried the example in section 1.9 Character Arrays. Here are the codes:

```
/* read a set of text lines and print the longest */

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line length */

/* declare functions: getline() and copy() */
int getline(char line[], int maxline); 
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* getline: read a line into array "s", return length */ 
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == "\n"){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';  /* the null character whose value is 0 */
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */ 
/* the return type of copy is "void" -- no value is returned */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')  /* terminated with a \0 */
        ++i; 
}

/* print the longest input line */
int main()
{
    int len;  /* current line length */ 
    int max;  /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];  /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    if (len > max) { 
        max = len;
        copy(longest, line); 
    }
    if (max>0) /* there was a line */ 
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0; 
}
```

There are two main errors:

1. error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
2. error: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here

The complete error list is here:

```
/Users/C/Codes/Ritchie/array_char.c:8: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
/usr/include/stdio.h:449: error: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
/Users/C/Codes/Ritchie/array_char.c:13: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
/usr/include/stdio.h:449: error: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
/Users/C/Codes/Ritchie/array_char.c: In function ‘getline’:
/Users//C/Codes/Ritchie/array_char.c:17: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
/Users/C/Codes/Ritchie/array_char.c:17: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior
```

I am not sure what went wrong, since it is exactly the same code from the book. Maybe the declaration of functions at the beginning:

```
int getline(char line[], int maxline); 
void copy(char to[], char from[]);
```

is problematic? Thank you!

Comment: Please post the actual error message (don't paraphrase)

Comment: Is there a reason to do everything the hard way here, or could you use `fgets` and `strcpy` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html

getline already exists in stdio.h. That is why you are getting the error. Change the function name to something else like getline_my.

Also, you are comparing a character with a string in line 16. It should be

`if(c == '\n')`

NOT

`if(c == "\n")`

Comment: Good spotting! I guess the OP typed the code in.

Comment: Well ofc the OP typed the code in. He's reading a book :P

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is likely a definition of `getline` in `stdio.h`. On my version of linux there is a getline function supplied by the C library (part of the POSIX standard I think). You can't have two functions with the same name in C, and this is your problem. Try renaming your version of `getline` to `my_getline` (both where you declare/define it and where you use it).

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:449: error: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
```

It's exactly as it says: `getline` is declared in `stdio.h` (because the standard library provides a function with that name). You cannot provide your own function with that name, because when you call `getline`, the compiler wouldn't know which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

From the date when that book was written up to nowadays the Standard C library modified a little, and they are not consistent any more the old and the new one.

You must remove the declarations, and leave the declarations from the current stdio.h.

Comment: This isn't from the standard changing. It's from gcc failing to conform with the standard.

Comment: He might be reading the second edition, which was updated to ANSI C, which should compile on any C compiler. (Also, the code he wrote should run on any C compiler besides the fact that the function name is already used so he needs to change it).

Comment: yes, the current gcc is c89 by default, unless you insert -c99. c11 also appeared.