# Old C code not compiling

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying this old example from "The C Programming Language". I am getting a conflicting types error with the `getline` function. I also tried placing the function before main. I am using gcc 4.6.3 as my compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main(void)
{
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max=0;
    while((len= getline(line, MAXLINE))>0)
        if(len>max){
            max=len;
            copy(longest,line);
        }

    if (max>0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c,i;

    for(i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i]=c;

    if(c=='\n'){
        s[i]=c;
        ++i;
}

    s[i]='\0';
    return i;
}


void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i=0;

    while((to[i]=from[i])!= '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the whole compiler error with line number?

Comment: Also, yo ucan't pass your array to getline like that.  You need to pass the array's address with &line, and then have the argument be of type char *.

Comment: @Magn3s1um: that's nonsense. An array of `char` can be passed to a fucntion taking `char*`. `char[]` as the type of an argument is a synonym for `char*`.

Comment: I think old style C though throws a compile error.  I'm not saying its wrong, just hte standard hadn't defined it at the time.

Comment: @Magn3s1um: the program is written in ANSI C89, as are all examples of K&R 2nd ed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning C by K&R, error when trying to compile programs from book with arrays and function calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763052/learning-c-by-kr-error-when-trying-to-compile-programs-from-book-with-arrays-a)

Answer (score 10):

`getline` is a [standard POSIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) nowadays, with a different signature than the function in this K&R example. Rename `getline` to something else and it should work.

Alternatively, compile with `gcc -std=c89` (or `-std=c99`) to get pure ISO C mode without POSIX or GNU extensions.

Answer (score 7):

Your `getline` function is clashing with [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) as provided by the standard library.  It'd be best to rename your function.