# How to implement custom versions of the getline function in stdio.h (CLANG, OS X) (ANSWER: Change POSIX standard used to compile)

Tags: c, clang, posix, getline, stdio

Good evening,

I am working through the exercises in Kernighan's and Ritchie's classic "The C Programming Language".

In several places the exercises have you creating your own version of a function that duplicates the name of of a function in the standard library.  Instead of creating an alternate name for my version, I would really like to tell the compiler that I would rather use my version of the function then the standard library function.

To get specific, if I try to compile a solution to exercise 1-18 which removes trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input I use a function 'getline' to read in the line from stdin. Unfortunately, this generates a compiler error because getline is defined in stdio.h.

I have tried using #undef, but couldn't seem to get that to work.

I have searched for other prior similar questions and found [this one][1]; however, it seems to require hacking the standard library header which I would rather not do.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Here is the code (stripped of my comments for shortness):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

static size_t getline(char s[], size_t lim) {

    char   c;
    size_t i = 0;

    while (--lim > 0 && (c = (char)getchar()) != (char)EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int main(void) {

    char   line[MAXLINE] = "";
    size_t len = 0;

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > MAXLINE)
            printf("%s", line);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And, the error I get is:

```
cc -std=c99 -Wall -g -I. -c -o obj/cleantrailsnblanks.o cleantrailsnblanks.c
cleantrailsnblanks.c:14:15: error: static declaration of 'getline' follows non-static declaration
static size_t getline(char s[], size_t lim) {
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:442:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
        ^
cleantrailsnblanks.c:35:40: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
                  ~~~~~~~              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:442:1: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [obj/cleantrailsnblanks.o] Error 1
```

**UPDATE 1**

After I dropped 'static' from my definition, the error changes to:

```
cc -std=c99 -Wall -g -I. -c -o obj/cleantrailsnblanks.o cleantrailsnblanks.c
cleantrailsnblanks.c:14:8: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
size_t getline(char s[], size_t lim) {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:442:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
        ^
cleantrailsnblanks.c:35:40: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2
while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
              ~~~~~~~              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:442:1: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [obj/cleantrailsnblanks.o] Error 1
```

**ANSWER**

Refer to this discussion:  [Why do I get a "conflicting types for getline" error when compiling the longest line example in chapter 1 of K&R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763052/why-do-i-get-a-conflicting-types-for-getline-error-when-compiling-the-longest)

The solution is to add these two lines prior to including stdio.h:

```
#undef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <stdio.h>
```

This sets the compiles the code using the POSIX.1-2001 standard as opposed to the POSIX.1-2008 standard in which the GNU getline() extension was added to the standard.

Comment: Remove the `static` qualifier.

Comment: Make sure the declaration of your function is the same as the standard function. So get rid of `static`.

Comment: I tried that too already since that is the the guidance provided by the error message and it still does not work.  I'll update my question with the results of that.

Comment: Also, my declaration will not be the same as the standard function because the K&R example of getline is not the same as the standard function.  This is one of the reasons I need to override and not have it consider the standard function definition.

Comment: "Instead of creating an alternate name for my version, I would really like to tell the compiler that I would rather use my version of the function then the standard library function." This is not what you are supposed to do while doing K&R exercises, really. K&R is an old book. If it tells you to use a name, and the name conflicts with something, just use another name. K&R would **not** ask you to use this name if they knew back in 1978 it will be predefined on most systems 40 years after.

Comment: Also, dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434733/kr-exercise-1-16-clang-conflicting-types-for-getline . Read all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to these two discussions (the second is the most relevant):

- [Why do I get a "conflicting types for getline" error when compiling    the longest line example in chapter 1 of K&R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763052/why-do-i-get-a-conflicting-types-for-getline-error-when-compiling-the-longest)
- [Can an ANSI C-compliant implementation include additional functions    in its standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376566/can-an-ansi-c-compliant-implementation-include-additional-functions-in-its-stand)

The solution is to add these two lines prior to including stdio.h:

```
#undef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <stdio.h>
```

This sets the compiles the code using the POSIX.1-2001 standard as opposed to the POSIX.1-2008 standard in which the GNU getline() extension was added to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think your exercice want to make you learn the **dynamic injection** and **shared library**.

Compile your file (without the `static`) like `gcc -shared -o libname.so filename.c`

On OS X you will need to set 3 environment variable :

- `setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH .`
- `setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES libname.so`
- `setenv DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE 1`

Some others information : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

**EDIT**

Let me show you an exemple by changing the result of `id`

```
$> id
uid=501(yourname) gid(staff) groups ...
```

Create a file `getuid.c`

```
int getuid() {
     return (0);
}

int geteuid() {
     return (0);
}
```

Compile with `gcc -shared -o myuid.so getuid.c`

You can write `nm myuid.so` and see the function inside.

then set your environment variable

```
setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH .
setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES libname.so
setenv DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE 1
```

it's could be with `export`, depends of your shell.

then `id` result look like :

```
$> id
uid=0(yourname) gid(staff) groups ...
```

Answer (score 0):

K&R is a (very) old book now, you need to take that in account. Declare/define `getline` exactly as the manual says (actually). As you are on OSX, the manual says:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  #include <stdio.h>
>
>  ssize_t
>  getline(char ** restrict linep, size_t * restrict linecapp, FILE * restrict stream);
> ```

Use **that** prototype.

You may also change the exercise a little bit and rename the function as `mygetline` if you really wish to use the original prototype.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you're going to use it.

If it's just in one .c file, I'd change your method name to something else, then either change all the calls to your new name or add a `#define realName overrideName` at the top of your file.

If this is more generic, or for mocking in unit testing, I would take your overridden `getline` method into its own .c file. Compiler it to a .so then tell your system about your override .so file before any other libraries when starting your app.