# Bad ptr error preventing pointer from being copied to an array of pointers

Tags: c

Doing exercise 5.7 from K&R:

> Rewrite readlines to store lines in an array supplied by main, rather than calling alloc to maintain storage. How much faster is the program?

What the program does is use an array of pointers to point at a bunch of lines that have been sorted by a quick sort algorithm, then printed out.

I'm choosing one huge array, `total_lines[]` to store each line fetched by `getline()` and I'm using a pointer p to point to the beginning of each of these lines in `Total_lines[]` so that I can then store the pointer addresses of the start of these lines in the array of pointers `lineptr[]`

However, after I return from `copy_lines()` back to `readlines()`, I'm getting an error in the auto window saying `p 0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>` and it doesn't copy to the pointer array here: `lineptr[nlines++] = p;`

Here is the code where something is going wrong:

```
#define MAXLEN 1000
int getline (char *, int);
char *alloc(int);
int copy_lines(char total_lines[], char line[], char *p);

int readlines (char *lineptr[], int maxlines, char total_lines[], int max_chars)
{
    int len, nlines;
    char *p, line[MAXLEN];
    p = 0;

    nlines = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
        if (nlines >= maxlines)
            return -1;
        else{
            line [len-1] = '\0';
            copy_lines(total_lines, line, p);
            //strcpy(p, line);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
            printf("%s\n", lineptr);
        }
        return nlines;
}
int copy_lines(char total_lines[], char lines[], char *p)
{
    static int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    total_lines[i] = lines[j++];
    p = total_lines+i; //point to the start of the next line
    i++;
    while(i < MAX_CHARS && (total_lines[i++] = lines[j++]))
        ;
    if (i == MAX_CHARS)
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Btw, VS gave me the error message `the variable p is being used without being initialized` when I tried to pass p into `copy_lines`, so I initialized it to zero. Is there a reason why I can't pass it without setting it to zero first?

Here is the entire code if anyone needs it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINES 5000
#define MAX_CHARS 50000
char *lineptr[MAXLINES];
int readlines (char *lineptr[], int nlines, char total_lines[], int max_chars);
void writelines (char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void qsort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right);

int main()
{
    int nlines;
    char total_lines[MAX_CHARS];

    if((nlines = readlines (lineptr, MAXLINES, total_lines, MAX_CHARS)) >= 0){
        qsort (lineptr, 0, nlines-1);
        writelines(lineptr, nlines);
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("error: input too big to sort\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
#define MAXLEN 1000
int getline (char *, int);
char *alloc(int);
int copy_lines(char total_lines[], char line[], char *p);

int readlines (char *lineptr[], int maxlines, char total_lines[], int max_chars)
{
    int len, nlines;
    char *p, line[MAXLEN];
    p = 0;

    nlines = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
        if (nlines >= maxlines)
            return -1;
        else{
            line [len-1] = '\0';
            copy_lines(total_lines, line, p);
            //strcpy(p, line);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
            printf("%s\n", lineptr);
        }
        return nlines;
}
int copy_lines(char total_lines[], char lines[], char *p)
{
    static int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    total_lines[i] = lines[j++];
    p = total_lines+i; //point to the start of the next line
    i++;
    while(i < MAX_CHARS && (total_lines[i++] = lines[j++]))
        ;
    if (i == MAX_CHARS)
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
void writelines (char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
        printf("%s\n", lineptr[i]);
}
void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;
    void swap (char *v[], int i, int j);

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    swap (v, left, (left + right)/2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
        if (strcmp (v[i], v[left]) < 0)
            swap (v, ++last, i);
    swap (v, left, last);
    qsort(v, left, last-1);
    qsort(v, last+1, right);
}
void swap (char *v[], int i, int j)
{
    char *temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
#define ALLOCSIZE 10000
static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char *allocp = allocbuf;

char *alloc(int n)
{
    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n){
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
int getline(char *s, int lim) // returns length of string if string size < buffer limit-2 (MAXLINE-2), else string length is incorrect
{
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 2 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        *s++ = c;
    if (c == '\n'){
        *s++ = c;
        i++;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I think the error you are getting is compiler specific. Initialization is not mandatory. Also the way you are using `p` in `copy_lines` is logically wrong. If you want to return some value to caller function using `p` you should save the value as `*p = <value>;`.

Comment: I'm not copying a value. I'm copying the address of `total_lines+i` `i=0` at that point.

Comment: Yeah! thats a problem, you cannot copy the address like that. For doing that you need pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: I fixed the code by moving the pointer into `copy_lines`. A pointer should be able to hold the address of anything of the same type. The pointer and the array are both type `char`

Comment: I'm still annoyed by this. I can't figure out why the pointer is not retaining its value once returned to `read_lines`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redefine `int getline (char *, int);`. libc already contains a `getline` function. (see `man getline`) Did you compile with warning enabled? Try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`. Rename `getline` to `getline2` or something else to avoid conflict with the previous declaration of `getline` in `stdio.h`.

As pointed out, since `getline` is not technically a **reserved word** it must be available for redefinition by a conforming ISO C implementation. **However**, as also pointed out, many of the ISO C implementations are **non-conforming** and will not allow this redefinition.

Comment: I don't really know much of how to use the IDE. How do you compile with commands like that? I'm using win Vista and VS Express 2010. I haven't gotten any errors about this.

Comment: Well, that's a good question. Generally any IDE will have a settings page for 'Compiler Options' or some similar settings entry. You usually find a text-box where you can enter additional compiler options either separated by a space or separated by a comma. A minimum set `-Wall -Wextra`. I don't use windows, my guess is you could find them in `Help`. If you are serious about learning programming, then you really should try using just the console so that you understand compiling and linking at its most basic. That way you then know what your IDE should be doing for you.

Comment: If operating in ISO C conforming mode, defining your own `getline` function must be permitted, since that is not a reserved identifier. (Apparently my install of gcc 4.8.3 is not conforming...) [Further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376566/can-an-ansi-c-compliant-implementation-include-additional-functions-in-its-stand/)

Comment: My 4.8.1 must be non-conforming as well. Thanks for the Further reading.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are passed by value in C. The variable `p` inside `copy_lines` is a different variable to `p` in `readlines`. When the function is called, the former is created and initialized with the value of the latter. You could remove some confusing by using a different name for each of these variables.

To allow one function to modify a variable local to another function, you must pass a pointer to that variable. A pointer to a `char *` has type `char **`.